IRA options for a small amount of self-employment income
Most of my income comes from investments so I understand it is considered non-earned and is not eligible for IRA contributions. However, I have a small amount of self-employment income and would like to maximize my IRA contributions and tax deductions, if any. Should I be using a Traditional IRA, a SEP IRA or both? Or something else altogether? And what is the maximum I can contribute? For simplicity assume the following:

MFJ (spouse has no income)
Age: 40s
$5,000 Self-employment income, individual
$150,000 Investment income (capital gains, dividends, interest)


Are you paying yourself via owners draw or a salary from your income?
Also, $5000 income seems pretty negligible compared to your hypothetical investment income. https://quickbooks.intuit.com/payroll/salary-or-draw-how-to-pay-yourself-as-business-owner/

With a total of $5K of earned income and no employees involved I see no reason why you'd consider SEP-IRA.
You might also want to consider Roth IRA, given that you're below the limits for contribution.

In that case what would be the maximum amount I can contribute? I think I need to subtract 15% for self employment tax, so would it be  $4,250?

Follow the IRS Pub. 590a

IRA or other qualified contributions do not exempt you from Social Security tax.  That will still need to be paid.  The only way to get around that is through paying yourself through dividends in an S-Corp.

@PeteB. Dividends are not earned income. Earned income is always subject to FICA or SE tax.
